# Why isn't Mosaico enabled in my CiviCRM Spark instance?

Tags: mosaico

CiviCRM Spark advertises including Mosaico email templates on the landing page (civicrm.com). Why doesn't it actually have Mosaico?

Comment: Hi and welcome Lee. Have you checked under Admin > System Settings > Extensions to see if it just needs Enabling?

Comment: Hi! Definitely should be there for some packages - worth checking https://civicrm.com/#pricing for the package you are on